# How do you completely uninstall git and Railsinstaller on Windows 7 for fresh re-install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, git, github

(Windows 7 64-bit) I had previously installed the Railsinstaller and did not follow through on using it. I uninstalled it using Revo Uninstaller, but now I'd like to reinstall it. After running the .exe, the command prompts comes up as it should, but I am not prompted to do the following as listed in the instructions:(http://railsinstaller.org/windows)

"Once installation is complete it should bring up the Windows Command Line (DOS prompt) asking for your name and email address.

Once you enter both you should see your generated public SSH key which you will need later."

It had already grabbed my previous git information. I do not want to use my previous information, I have a new account and would like to use that.

Any info on how to remove the git info would be helpful.

Things I've done: uninstalled Railsinstaller with Revo.

Removed C:\Users\/.git

Deleted any appdata related to git

Removed one registry key (can't recall which one)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your `.gitconfig` file from the directory pointed at by the `$HOME` environment variable.